# Users have different duplicity versions

Tags: 14.04, apt, sudo, duplicity

I've just installed the latest version of duplicity (0.7.18 at the time of writing) using [these instructions](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/duplicity) to add the ppa then update.

I did this under my account which has sudo privileges and installed the package. Duplicity gives me the new version whether I become root or not.

```
james@box # duplicity --version
duplicity 0.7.18.1
```

However, when logged in as another non-sudoers user, duplicity shows the old version. I've tried logging out and back in again.

```
nasuser@box # duplicity --version
duplicity 0.7.14
```

With both users I get:

```
which duplicity
/usr/bin/duplicity
```

How do I get the non-root user(s) to see the updated version - 0.7.18.1?

And in general how does this kind of thing work? Does that /usr/bin/duplicity file really get called both times when the --version option is used, only referring to two different files elsewhere? Or is *which* not such a great tool as there are things it doesn't know about?

Comment: According to [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=duplicity) 14.04 LTS should have 0.6.23. How did you get 0.7.1x?

Comment: Ah good question. I have been installing python pip packages which may include that one. Would just like to understand how this works, as they look like the same file.

Comment: Then we have two methods of `duplicity` installation: from deb-package by APT (check with `apt-cache policy duplicity`) and by pip (check with `pip show duplicity` / `pip3 show duplicity` for current user and `sudo pip show duplicity` / `sudo pip3 show duplicity` for system-wide). You can compare versions and methods on two machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @N0rbert helpfully pointed out, pip had installed a local version of duplicity which the nasuser account was picking up and `pip show duplicity` showed this:

`/home/nasuser/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

To remove this I used:

`pip uninstall duplicity`

Then `duplicity --version` returned the same thing for both users.